# Safari 14: how to view cookies' content

Tags: macos, safari, cookies

In Safari 14 for Mac, how can I view the contents of the cookies set by a given site? I know how to delete them, but I would like to see exactly what's in them.

I have tried loading the site with Safari's Developer Tools, but the "Cookies" section in the inspector didn't have anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cookies section is what you're looking for in the Developer Tools. Inspect it for this site, Stack Exchange, and you'll see a number of cookies and their values.

Inspect Element > Storage > Cookies